# Run time error 3061, too few parameters, expected 2

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error

Im having trouble with this one segment of my code where Im just trying to insert 4 values into their respective 4 fields in a table called SumTable. I looked up several solutions and looks like nothing is wrong. I used Debug.Print and it shows the exact line I want to be executed.
("INSERT INTO SumTable VALUES (Bailey,Jessica,4,2);")
It shouldnt be complicated, I dont understand what it wants from me.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

`

```
            Dim data As DAO.Database 
            Set data = CurrentDb
            DoCmd.OpenTable "SumTable", acViewNormal, acAdd
            Str_Sql = "INSERT INTO SumTable VALUES (" & strlast & "," & first & "," & count & "," & countfin & ");"
            Debug.Print Str_Sql
            data.Execute Str_Sql
            DoCmd.Close acTable, "SumTable", acSaveYes`
```

Comment: If you're just executing an INSERT INTO statement, you shouldn't need to open or close the table.  The execution of the SQL statement alone should be sufficient to insert the desired record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first two variables are strings, you will need to wrap them in single quotes. Something like:

```
Str_Sql = "INSERT INTO SumTable VALUES ('" & strlast & "','" & first & "'," & count & "," & countfin & ");"
```

I would also suggest renaming `count` as it is a reserved word in Access - [List of Reserved Words in Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words). This will stop other problems in future.